# Is there an open mapping theorem for affine morphisms?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be rings. If $\varphi : A \longrightarrow B$ is such that $^a\varphi : Spec(B) \longrightarrow Spec(A)$ is bijective, then in what conditions $^a\varphi$ is a homeomorphism? Or, more general, in what conditions $^a\varphi$ is open if one assume only surjectiveness?

If I pick the constructible topology on the spectrum (applying the functor $(\bullet)^{Bool}$ that makes the space Boolean), then it will be a homeomorphism. So I was thinking about creating some way of returning back any information from the Boolean space to the original space when I restrict $A$ and $B$ to be some kind of rings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the notation ${}^a\varphi$ mean?  Is it the map $\mathfrak{p} \mapsto \varphi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$?

Comment: @dmdmdmdmdmd Yes

Comment: Am I missing something then?  The induced map on spectra is continuous, so if it's additionally bijective, then...

Comment: @dmdmdmdmdmd then it's a bijective continuous map. The inverse not necessarily is continuous.

Comment: Trivial example: $\phi$ surjective

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is normal, and $^a\varphi$ bijective, then $^a\varphi$ is an isomorphism of affine varieties. This is Corollary 17.4.6 in Tauvel & Yu (Lie Algebras and Algebraic Groups), I am sure it can be found in other places as well.